# One Universal Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

Greeting,

So we have a backend admin desktop app (accessible by the company employees only) and a public frontend web app that's accessible by anyone and it allows user creation. 
We have a Roles table and all users (employees and non-employees) have roles assigned to them; however all user are stored in one table.

Is it a good practice to store all users in one table as opposed to having two different tables one for the employees and the second for users that sign up through the webapp?

Your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: There really isn't a right answer for this. There are solid arguments to both sides of this coin. Personally, I would use a single table as it makes maintenance easier because all the data for users (regardless of type) are found in one location.

Comment: Seen this work either way. Best answer probably depends on usage. If employees share function with generic web user, a single integrated login (sharing a common table) might make the most sense. If the functions have little overlap, a separate table might make the most sense. From a security viewpoint, having a separate website for employees via VPN may be best choice. You will have to decide what works best for you.

Comment: 1 vote for the single table method.

Answer (score 1):

My first reaction is that this sounds like a bad architecture.  My reaction is based on a simple reason:  employees should be using backend systems that are behind a firewall.  The public web system is not behind the firewall.  Hence, they should have different provisioning for security.

Your ask about one table versus multiple tables for security.  For a single application, you should have a single table.  This could even be shared among multiple applications, but I would definitely distinguish between internal and public applications.

You don't say anything about how the roles might interact with each other, but I could see further confusion if, say, an employee is "admin" on the internal system but just a regular user on the public system.